# How to transfer data from Kafka to Cassandra using Nifi?

Tags: cassandra, nullpointerexception, apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I want to collect the data from `Kafka` using `Nifi` in `Cassandra`. I created a flow like this for this.[image: My flow here]

My database connection configuration is like this:
[image]

This is my configurations for my ConvertJsonToSQL processor:
[image]

I encounter the following error on my ConvertJsonToSQL processor.

> ConvertJSONToSQL[id=d25a7e27-0167-1000-2d9a-2c969b33482a] ConvertJSONToSQL[id=d25a7e27-0167-1000-2d9a-2c969b33482a] failed to process session due to null; Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec: java.lang.NullPointerException

Note: I added `dbschema` driver jar to `Nifi` library.

What do you think I should do to solve this problem?

Comment: Datastax recently released a Kafka Connect plugin, by the way. https://github.com/datastax/kafka-examples And the one from Landoop works as well... Point being Kafka Connect is built into Kafka Framework, so are you sure you need Nifi?

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm looking for the cause of this error. I don't need a different tool.

Comment: Well, it's hard to really say without the entire stacktrace of the NPE and probably stepping into some Nifi source code to see what exactly is null

Comment: @cricket_007 I guess you're right, I just wanted to ask you here, saying that maybe there's been an encounter.

Comment: I would suggest making a [mcve], though. The ConvertJSONToSQL processor is the problem. You've not shown your JSON, or it's configuration... You could just as easily be reading a JSON file, converting that to SQL with that processor, then writing the queries to disk... I'm not sure Kafka or Cassandra are really part of the problem that needs to be diagnosed here

Comment: Unless you share the entire stacktrace of the error, we wouldn't be able to help. Having said that, if you're looking for a way to ingest Kafka events into Cassandra, the flow you have written may not be the perfect one, rather you can try `ConsumeKafkaRecord -> PutCassandraRecord`

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman I want to save twitter data to `cassandra` using `kafka`, how can I put the `json` file back from `twitter` api? I want to add each json data as a line in cassandra.

Comment: @cricket_007 DataStax Kafka Connector works only with DSE & DDAC...

Comment: @AlexOtt I thought I heard on y'alls YouTube talk about it that it would work with  Cassandra as well. Or are you suggesting the Datastax Java Driver doesn't work with vanilla Cassandra?

Comment: @cricket_007 Only DataStax Basic, DSE, and DataStax Distribution of Apache Cassandra are supported...

Comment: In any case, my point still holds. We need to see a sample of the JSON data, and ideally also the Cassandra namespace definition (e.g. expected inputs and outputs)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the available information it is difficult to troubleshoot the error, the most likely reason for the ConvertJSONToSQL to fail is an invalid JSON. Just one point from the [documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertJSONToSQL/index.html):

> The incoming FlowFile is expected to be "flat" JSON message, meaning that it consists of a single JSON element and each field maps to a simple type.

I cannot see what you did in the AttributesToJSON processor, but I believe twitter will typically return a nested JSON, and that you might not have flattened it enough.

---

A simple generic way to troubleshoot this, is to start processors from the top, and inspect the queue before/after each processor untill you see something you don't expect.

With this you should be able to pinpoint the problem exactly, and if needed you can use the information discovered in this way to create a reproducible example and ask a more detailed question.